# SQL query for getting 1st and last record of each day between selected dates. Data is recorded every 10 mins

Tags: sql, sql-server

MyTable

```
---------------------------------
time                   value
_________________________________
2023-10-13 00:08:00        15 
2023-10-13 00:18:00        13
2023-10-13 00:28:00        14
2023-10-13 00:38:00        28
|
|
|
|
2023-10-13 23:38:00        23 
2023-10-13 23:48:00        45
2023-10-13 23:58:00        25
2023-10-14 00:08:00        2
2023-10-14 00:18:00        64
|
|
2023-10-14 23:48:00        2
2023-10-14 23:58:00        6
|
|
2023-10-20 03:08:00        5 
2023-10-20 03:18:00        93
2023-10-20 03:28:00        24
2023-10-20 03:38:00        58
```

The desired result should look like

```
Date                     startVal              end val
2023-10-13                 15                     25
2023-10-14                 2                       6
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
select format(time, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as Date, min(value) as startVal, max(value) as endVal 
from MyTable 
where time between '2023-10-13' and '2023-10-20' 
group by format(time, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: that should give an error

Comment: `format(time, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as Date,` that isn't confusing at all... I really suggest giving your columns meaningful names. A column called `time` that isn't a `time` is quite misleading.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to use a common table expression, `first_value` and `distinct`.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
    ([time] datetime, [value] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO MyTable 
    ([time], [value])
VALUES
    ('2023-10-13 00:08:00', 15),
    ('2023-10-13 00:18:00', 13),
    ('2023-10-13 00:28:00', 14),
    ('2023-10-13 00:38:00', 28),
    ('2023-10-13 23:38:00', 23),
    ('2023-10-13 23:48:00', 45),
    ('2023-10-13 23:58:00', 25),
    ('2023-10-14 00:08:00', 2),
    ('2023-10-14 00:18:00', 64),
    ('2023-10-14 23:48:00', 2),
    ('2023-10-14 23:58:00', 6),
    ('2023-10-20 03:08:00', 5),
    ('2023-10-20 03:18:00', 93),
    ('2023-10-20 03:28:00', 24),
    ('2023-10-20 03:38:00', 58)
;
```

The query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT CAST([time] As Date) As TheDate, 
           CAST([time] As Time) As TheTime,
           [Value]
     FROM MyTable 
)
SELECT DISTINCT TheDate, 
       FIRST_VALUE([value]) OVER(PARTITION BY TheDate ORDER BY TheTime) As FirstValue,
       FIRST_VALUE([value]) OVER(PARTITION BY TheDate ORDER BY TheTime DESC) As LastValue
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
TheDate         FirstValue  LastValue
2023-10-13      15          25
2023-10-14      2           6
2023-10-20      5           58
```

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/fMX3Z5Qn)

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
select convert(date,[time]) [Date]
    ,max(case when rn=1 then [value] end ) FirstValue
    ,max(case when rn=cnt then [value] end) LastValue 
FROM (
    SELECT [time],  [Value]
        ,row_number()over(partition by convert(date,[time]) order by time) rn
        ,count(*)over(partition by convert(date,[time]) ) cnt
     FROM MyTable  
) CTE
group by convert(date,[time])
```

There 2 `Sort` operations.